# Pandas calculate mean of column minus in multi column data

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have dataframe as below

```
                       BTC               ETH
time(index)      high      low     high        low 
     1            3         1       4           2
     2            4         1       4           1
```

and I want mean on `index`, of minus between `high` & `low`

by each column like below..

```
                      BTC                ETH
                      2.5                2.5
```

Is there any way using `pandas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select by second level of `MultiIndex`, subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and get `mean`:

```
s = df.xs('high', axis=1, level=1).sub(df.xs('low', axis=1, level=1)).mean()
print (s)
BTC    2.5
ETH    2.5
dtype: float64
```

If want one row `DataFrame` add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = s.to_frame().T
print (df)
   BTC  ETH
0  2.5  2.5
```

or [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.xs('high', axis=1, level=1).sub(df.xs('low', axis=1, level=1)).agg(['mean'])
print (df)
      BTC  ETH
mean  2.5  2.5
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.xs('high', axis=1, level=1))
   BTC  ETH
1    3    4
2    4    4

print (df.xs('high', axis=1, level=1).sub(df.xs('low', axis=1, level=1)))
   BTC  ETH
1    2    2
2    3    3
```